# remove negative axes from coreplot(scatter plot) in iphone

Tags: iphone, core-plot

How to remove negative axes from corePlot(scatterplot) in iphone and how to set the area of graph that is visible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here are some examples pulled from the *CPTTestApp* example included with Core Plot:

1. Setting plot ranges:

   ```
   CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
   plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(0.0)
                                                   length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(-10.0)];
   plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(0.5)
                                                   length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(1500.0)];
   ```

   Remember that plot ranges are similar to `NSRange`—they have a starting location and length. The length can be negative if you want the reverse the direction of an axis.
2. Limiting the length of axes:

   ```
   yAxis.visibleRange   = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInteger(2)
                                                       length:CPTDecimalFromInteger(3)];
   yAxis.gridLinesRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInteger(2)
                                                       length:CPTDecimalFromInteger(3)];
   ```
3. Changing the visible area:

   ```
   graph.paddingLeft = 60.0;
   graph.paddingTop = 60.0;
   graph.paddingRight = 60.0;
   graph.paddingBottom = 60.0;
   ```

   You can also set padding on `graph.plotAreaFrame` to inset the plot area to create room for axis labels and titles.

Eric

Comment: I'm trying to figure out core plot.  Can you tell me where I can find explanation on CPTXYPlotSpace.  I see you have a range that looks like it should go from 0 to -10.  If you did that, I'd think that it would include negative values.

Comment: Exactly. The location of a plot range is the left end (for the x-axis) or bottom (for the y-axis). A positive length counts upwards towards higher values while a negative length counts down to lower values.

Answer (score 1):

Use `plotRangeWithLocation: length:` methods.

```
-(void)initXYAxesRanges{

    //Set graph ranges for x and y planes
    CPXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    plotSpace.xRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(0)
                                                   length:CPDecimalFromFloat(10];
    plotSpace.yRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(0)
                                                   length:CPDecimalFromFloat(10)];
}
```

Comment: i have given this ,so there are no numbers shown in this region but the axes are still visible....and also how to change the visible area of graph?